# Recharts 2.0.8 <ResponsiveContainer> </ResponsiveContainer> not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, react-hooks, recharts

I am running into a issue where I am not able to use Rechart's `<ResponsiveContainer></ResponsiveContainer>` in IE11.

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={x + (y ? 10 : 0)}>
                    <BarChart...>
</BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

while the above code works well with other browsers but with IE 11, I get below error:

> The above error occurred in the  component:
> in ResizeDetector (created by ResponsiveContainer)
> in ResponsiveContainer (at chart-widget.tsx:286)
> in div (at chart-widget.tsx:285)
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize e

As soon as I change `<ResponsiveContainer></ResponsiveContainer>` tags with simple `<div></div>` tag as below, charts are rendered properly in IE11.

```
<div width="100%" height={x + (y ? 10 : 0)}>
                    <BarChart...>
</BarChart>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me why the `<ResponsiveContainer>` tag is not working in IE11 and how can I get this working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: I tested it and It runs ok on IE11, you should check your bundle configuration.

Comment: @lissettdm Yes we are using create-react-app?

Comment: @lissettdm Did you tried with version 2.0.8 as downgrading works for use  as well but for some reason we wanted to use the 2.0.8 version of Recharts

Comment: sorry, I tried with version 2.0.9 and it  works like a charm, I will tried with 2.0.8

Comment: see my answer, let me to know if that fix your problem

Comment: @lissettdm Thanks a lot for this, I am trying it now :)

Comment: I test lissettdm's solution and it works well in IE 11. I suggest that you can mark the answer as accepted. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @lissettdm I tested it and your solution works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with `recharts@2.0.8` and I get the same error. The error occurs because `ResizeDetector` use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) who is not supported by IE. Using this [polyfil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill)l fix the problem:

```
npm install resize-observer-polyfill
```

In your index.js:

```
import 'resize-observer-polyfill/dist/ResizeObserver.global'
```

With `recharts@2.0.9` the problem is solved.